Understanding the relation between probability distribution, cumulative probability function and continuous random variables.
Up until now I only considered discrete random variables. At the moment I am trying to understand the non-discrete terminology in probability theory better.
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $X$ a random variable on this space.
Definition 1:
The probability distribution of $X$, denoted as $P_X$, is defined as $P_X(S)=P(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in S\}):=P(X \in S)$.
Definition 2:
The cumulative distribution function of $X$, denoted as $F_X$, is defined as:
$F_X(x):=P(X \leq x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Definition 3: (continuous random variable)
We say that $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous random variable, if there exists a (measurable) function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that
$P(X \in S)=\int_S f(x) dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)1_S(x) dx$, for every (measurable) $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. If $X$ continuous, then the density is given by the derivation of the cumulative distribution function.
Here are my thoughts on the above definitions:
About Definition 1: Here the definition is the same as in the discrete rv case.
About Definition 2: The cumulative probability function si defined as
$F_X(x):=P(X \leq x)$ which, written out is $P(\{\omega \in \Omega:X(\omega) \leq x \})$. Thus $F_X(x)=P(X^{-1}((-\infty,x]))=P_X(X \in (-\infty,x])$.
This means, if we ignore technicalities, given a random variable $X$ the probability distribution of $X$ is a function that takes some set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ as input and gives the probability $P(X \in S)$ as output.
Then the cumulative probability function (of $X$), is defined by the probability distribution of $X$, where we consider cumulating sets $(-\infty,x] $. This would mean that the cumulative probability function depends only on the probability distribution of $X$.
Question 1: Are my thoughts on Definiton 2 resp. the relation between probability distribution and cumulative probability function correct thus far?
About Definition 3:
Definition 3 is confusing. I would have expected the definition of $X$ being continuous to be something like: $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if it is continuous at all $\omega \in \Omega$. And continuity at a point if the $\epsilon - \delta$ criterion holds (alternatively, if $lim_{a \rightarrow b} X(b)=X(a)$ holds).
But instead, we say $X$ is continuous, if there exists a function $f$ such that we can calculate the probability destribution of $X$, $P(X \in S)$ through integration of the set $S$. I do not see how this implies continuity.
Question 2:
Why is continuity of a rarndom variable defined in such a different way then one (or at least me) would expect?

Your definition of a continuous random variable is only used by those who do not know measure theory, What you call  as continuous random variable shold be called absolutely continuous random variable. A continuous random variable is one whose CDF is a continuous function.

$\Omega$ does not come with a  topology, so you cannot define continuity of $\omega \to X(\omega)$.

@geetha290krm Thank you for that remark.
